# How to translate Fluent to Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, fluent

so i wanna try to get a filtering tag method, but in the database part is where i get lost, well kind of, because i wrote a raw query that works, but i need the Eloquent result so i can play with the relationships from the model class.

So here is the raw query:

```
$peticion = DB::select(DB::Raw("SELECT P.id, P.titulo, P.deadline, P.created_at, P.respuesta_id, U.usuario, C.titulo as categoria, C.clase_css as css, TG.Etiqueta
                                    FROM peticiones P

                                        JOIN usuarios U ON U.id = P.usuario_id

                                        JOIN categorias C ON C.id = P.categoria_id

                                        LEFT JOIN (
                                                SELECT PT.peticion_id, T.nombre as Etiqueta
                                                FROM tags T
                                                    JOIN peticion_tag PT ON PT.tag_id = T.id
                                        ) AS TG ON TG.peticion_id = P.id

                                        JOIN (
                                                SELECT PP.peticion_id 
                                                FROM (
                                                    SELECT PT.peticion_id, count(PT.peticion_id) AS conteo
                                                    FROM peticion_tag PT 
                                                    WHERE PT.tag_id IN ( $etiquetas )
                                                    GROUP BY PT.peticion_id
                                                ) PP
                                                WHERE PP.conteo = $len ) AS PPP
                                    ON P.id = PPP.peticion_id
                                    WHERE P.categoria_id = $id ;"));
```

what it does is that retrieve all the peticiones who has as many tags in it something like this in SO when filtering by tags.

But as i said i need the eloquent so this is my attempt to recreate the raw query:

```
$pet = Peticion::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags, $len){

                                $q->whereIn('tag_id', $tags);

                            })
                            ->where('categoria_id', '=', $id)
                            ->get();
```

But it returns me all the peticiones who has this tag OR this tag, OR as many has the $tags array this get achieved with the raw query in the

```
WHERE PP.conteo = $len
```

but i dont know how to translate to eloquent.
Hope someone can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: As simple workaround, for convert results from the raw query to models, you can try this: `Petition::hydrateRaw($petition)`

Comment: thanks, i gave a try but throws me an exception... array to string conversion, do i have to pass another parameter the method hydrateRaw(string $query, array $bindings = array() ) what is that bindings stand for???

Comment: Sorry for unclear solution. Do not call the `::select` method. Just save the result of `::raw` to a variable (`$raw = DB::raw(...)`) and then call `$petitions = Petition::hydrateRaw($raw)`

Comment: yup... it worked, but not as fancy as i wanted... theres some part when the Tags is a many to many relationship, so for example a Peticion with 3 tags returns me a Collection with 3 items... but it supposed to retrieve me only 1 and an array with that 3 tags... and the raw query not works like that... how can i achieve that??

Comment: Ok, in this case you can try to use the `join` method on eloquent query builder but with raw statements inside it. Here is example, how you can do that: http://www.rickywiens.ca/blog/making-raw-join-queries-with-eloquent-and-laravel/ . You just need 2 simple joins and 2 raw. If you'll provide me with an github repo with migrations, seeders and unit test for checking results, I can try to help you with implementing.